# mysql-ndb-operator kubernetes IP issue. ERROR: Unable to connect with connect string:

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I am trying to test the MySQL ndb cluster operator (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-ndb-operator). I get it all running but since I use a pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 each machine gets an IP in the range 10.244. but when I login to the management node and run ndb_mgm>SHOW I get "ERROR: Unable to connect with connect string: nodeid=0,192.168.0.2:1186". Of course, this is a correct error but I need a way to let the operator know that
IP range. Unfortunately, I cannot find any way to do this. Does anyone have any idea?

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-ndb-operator/blob/main/deploy/manifests/ndb-operator.yaml

by the way, even if I do change the pod-network-cidr when installing something else like weave it takes the IPs that ndb cluster wants i.e 192.168.0.2 so that is no the answer.